# How to cite a revised second edition?

Tags: citations, books

So, I am trying to cite a book in the References section of my paper, and the publication information on the book cover is really confusing, which is as follows:

> AN INTRODUCTION TO WITTGENSTEIN'S TRACTATUS
>
> Copyright(c) G.E.M. Anscombe 1959
> Printed in the United States of America
>
> This book was originally published in 1959 in the Philosophy division, edited by Professor H. J. Paton, of the Hutchinson University Library, with a second edition, revised, in 1963. It is here reprinted by arrangement.
>
> First Harper Torchbook edition published 1965 by
> Harper & Row, Publishers, Incorporated
> 49 East 33rd Street
> New York, N.Y. 10016

How should I cite this book? (say, in Harvard style).

Comment: What is the Harvard style for a reference? And why do you think this will not fit?

Comment: Okay, forget about the Harvard style. Regardless of the style, what's exactly the year of publication of this book? 1959? 1963? 1965? and What's the name of the publisher? Harper & Row, Publishers, Incorporated <--- this whole thing?

Comment: You reference the book you are using, not any one of 50 previous prints.

Answer (score 1):

Great question!

Among other challenges, citing this book is not easy because it is part of a series, and the publisher's name is very similar to the series name.

- *Publisher*: Hutchinson & Co.
- *Series*: Hutchinson University Library (Philosophy)
- *Series editor*: H. J. Paton

I prefer the *Chicago Manual of Style*, 17th ed. (2017) (hereafter, *Chicago*), Notes and Bibliography format. I consulted *Chicago* to write the citations below.

I would cite the book in a **note** (footnote) like this:

> G. E. M. Anscombe, *An Introduction to Wittgenstein's Tractatus*, 2nd ed. (1963; repr., New York: Harper & Row, 1965), 27–29. Citations refer to the 1965 Harper & Row reprint.

If I were to cite the book a second time, I would use a **shortened citation** ("short form") like this:

> Anscombe, *Introduction to Wittgenstein's Tractatus*, 34.

In the **bibliography** I would cite the book like this:

> Anscombe, G. E. M. [Gertrude Elizabeth Margaret]. *An Introduction to Wittgenstein's Tractatus*. 2nd ed., repr. New York: Harper & Row, 1965. First published 1963 by Hutchinson (London). Page references are to the 1965 Harper & Row reprint.

### Notes

- Professor Anscombe preferred initials instead of her lengthy given name, but since her full name appears occasionally, I chose to provide it in the bibliography.
- I made up the page numbers for the note citations.
- The names of both publishers are not required for the note, but should be included in the bibliography.
- *Chicago* states that "2nd ed." is enough, i.e., "rev." (revised) is not necessary because most readers assume that a 2nd edition includes revisions.
- *Chicago* advises against citing the series name and editor in most instances.

### Sources consulted

- AbeBooks.com
- Google Books
- Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy
- The Chicago Manual of Style *Online*
- WorldCat.org